# find duplicate counts and records on multiple key in csv files python

Tags: python, csv

hey iam using python version 2.5.1 .

hi want to count the duplicate records and records  in the entire file  . can any one help me . count should not contains any Counter or OrderedDict function . Above 2 functions are not there in python 2.5.1 version

```
dup_s_output = []
seen=set()

for row1 in sort_src:
#print (row1)
    if row1  in seen :
        dup_s_output.append(row1)
    seen.add(row1)
```

Comment: You should use a dictionary instead of a two lists.

Comment: If you don't mind using other libraries, `pandas` can easily read csv files and has a function, `DataFrame.duplicated`, that will identify duplicates very easily.

Comment: What is the key? The whole row, or a set of columns within each row? And what are you after - counts for each duplicated row or count of all dups?

Comment: is it possible the only issue is that you have `.apend()` instead of `.append()`?

Answer (score 0):

if the order of the entries are not important I'd recommend using dictionaries to keep track of the recurrences:

```
sort_src = list("hello world") #for testing
seen = {}
for row1 in sort_src:
    seen[row1] = seen.get(row1,0) + 1
    #if the row is already in the dict then it's value is increased by 1
    #if the row is not in the dict then .get() returns 0 (then add 1

for r in seen:
    print(r,"occured",seen[r],"times")
```

if the order of the rows does matter the same could be applied with `collections.OrderedDict()`

```
import collections
seen = collections.OrderedDict()
```

either way `seen.keys()` will give you a list of unique entries and `.items()` will be a list of (entry, count) tuples.

EDIT - to count just the number of duplicates you need to sum up the total entries (dict.values()) then subtract the number of unique entries (len of dict)

```
 num_of_dup_entries = sum(seen.values()) - len(seen)
```

Comment: note that this will only work when row1 is a hashable object but the same restriction applies to use of sets which you are using so I don't think that will impede you.

Comment: from the above code m getting count but i duplicate records are not coming can any one help me on this    below is my code                                                                   f= open('bravo_temp_src24.csv','rb')
c = Counter(key(row) for row in csv.reader(f))
ptr1= c.most_common()
dups = [t for t in c.most_common() if t[1] > 1]
    # or, if you prefer a dict
dups_dict = {row: count for row, count in c.most_common() if count > 1}

Comment: i am looking for duplicate count in source n target , duplicates records in source n target  , common records in both , missing records in both

Comment: m getting index out of range error key =itemgetter(0,2,4)
with open('bravo_temp_files1.csv') as f:
    c = Counter(key(row) for row in csv.reader(f))
    dups = [t for t in c.most_common() if t[1] > 1]
    # or, if you prefer a dict
    dups_dict = {row: count for row, count in c.most_common() if count > 1}

Comment: i am using python 2.5.1 version .In Python 2.5.1 Counter function is not there so can any one help code without using counter function .It will great help

Comment: the code I have suggested _does **not** use the Counter function_, I'm really confused what is not working for you...

Comment: hi Tadhg McDonald-Jensen,i'll explain my requirement  , lets assume based on key (0,1,2,3) i am checking duplicates .my python version 2.5 . counter function OrderedDict function are not there in this version . In the above code i checked based on only one key

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question mentions "multiple key", which I assume to mean that the key consists of a subset of the CSV fields. Since you are after counts you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter

key = itemgetter(0,2,4)    # for example: columns 0, 2 and 4 comprise the key

with open('data.csv') as f:
    c = Counter(key(row) for row in csv.reader(f))
    dups = [t for t in c.most_common() if t[1] > 1]
    # or, if you prefer a dict
    dups_dict = {row: count for row, count in c.most_common() if count > 1}
```

Or, if you are comparing entire rows your key could be each line:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('data.csv') as f:
    c = Counter(f)
    dups = [t for t in c.most_common() if t[1] > 1]
    dups_dict = {row: count for row, count in c.most_common() if count > 1}
```

In both cases above I used [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) as a convenient way to order the `dups` list by descending count frequency. You can just use `Counter.items()` if that is not important or if you are generating `dups_dict`, for which there is no inherent order.

Comment: Above code for entire row is not working for key is working , i ve one doudt how to extract only count values for entire file help me on this

Comment: In what way does the "entire row" code not work? As for the count values, do you want the per duplicate counts, or the total number of duplicates? Do you even need to keep the line, or do you just want the count?

Comment: i want to write duplicates into another files and duplicates count to display

Answer (score 0):

```
len(dup_s_output)
```

The above would return the number of items in your list.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to have a basic counter class to use in python 2.5:

```
class BasicCounter(dict):
    def update(self,iterable):
        for thing in iterable:
            self[thing] = self.get(thing,0) + 1

    def __init__(self,iterable=None):
        dict.__init__(self)
        if iterable:
            self.update(iterable)
```

All the other posted answers are counting duplicate `rows` instead of entries within a row, to get a count for each row individually you can use this:

```
row_counts = []
for row in sort_src:
    row_count.append(BasicCounter(row))
```

Or to ignore the separation of rows completely and count duplicate entries in entire file you can use this:

```
entry_count = BasicCounter()
for row in sort_src:
    entry_count.update(row)
```

Hope one of these is what you are looking for!